# Differentiate the Function: y=$\ ln\ tan^2x$

Tags: calculus

y=$(ln\ tan^2x)$

= $2(ln\ tan\ x)\cdot (ln\ tan\ x)'$

=$2(ln\ tan\ x)\cdot \frac{1}{(tan\ x)'}$

=$\frac{2(ln\ tan\ x)}{sec^2x}$

Is this right if not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\ln(\tan^2x)\not=(\ln(\tan x))^2$.

Comment: No. The fuction to differentiate is $\ln((\tan x)^2)$.

Comment: so mu next step would be $2\ln((\tan x)) \cdot ln(tan)^2x\ cdot\frac{1}{sec^2x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make mistakes when applying the chain rule.

The function you are differentiating is:

> Take $x$, calulate tangent, then square and last calculate logarithm.

You must begin by the end, that is, you must differentiate the logarithm first:

$$y'=\frac{(\tan^2 x)'}{\tan^2x}$$

Now differentiate the square:

$$y'=\frac{2\tan x(\tan x)'}{\tan^2x}$$

And finally, differentiate the tangent and make some cosmetic simplifications:
$$y'=\frac{2\tan x(1+\tan^2x)}{\tan^2x}=\frac{2+2\tan^2x}{\tan x}=2\cot x+2\tan x$$

Comment: @zahbaz's result and mine are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the original function as $y=ln( \tan^2x)$. Let me know if this is what you intended. Then, remembering $\frac{d}{du} \ln u = 1/u$ and the chain rule, we get

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{1}{\tan^2x} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\tan^2x \\\\ & = \frac{1}{\tan^2x} \cdot 2\tan x \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\tan x \\\\ & = \frac{1}{\tan^2x} \cdot 2\tan x \cdot \sec^2x \\\\ & = \frac{2 \sec^2x}{\tan x}  \\\\ & = \frac{2 \sec x}{\sin x}  \\\\ & = 2 \sec x\ \csc x  
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a start: ln(tan^2(x)) = ln((tan(x)^2) = 2*ln(tan(x)) this should make the differentiation process trivial and will yield: 
2*(csc(x))*(sec(x)) or more succinctly - 2csc(x)sec(x)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\ln(\tan^2(x))\right)=\frac{d}{dx} \left(2\ln(\tan(x))\right)=$$
$$2\frac{d}{dx} \left(\ln(\tan(x))\right)=2\cot(x)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan(x)\right)=$$
$$2\cot(x)\sec^2(x)=2\csc(x)\sec(x)=4\csc(2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$(\ln(\tan^2(x)))' = (2\ln(\tan(x))' = 2 \frac{\tan'(x)}{\tan(x)} = 2\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos^2(x)} = \frac{2}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} = \frac{4}{\sin(2x)}$